# Derivation of the adjoint Poisson equation

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, duality-theorems, adjoint-operators, poissons-equation

I'm trying to follow the derivation of the adjoint Poisson equation provided in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_BOhFq58T8), but I'm getting tripped up on some of the steps that are skipped. Here is my derivation in full. Questions at the end.

Consider the minimization problem

\begin{align}
\min_a J(u, a, \vec{x}) = \int_{\Omega} c u(a, \vec{x}) \ dV
\end{align}

over the domain $\Omega$ bounded by $\partial \Omega$ subject to the PDE constraint (Poisson's equation) given by

\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot (a(\vec{x}) \nabla u(\vec{x})) - f(\vec{x}) = 0
\end{align}

where $a(\vec{x})$ is the design variable and $f(\vec{x})$ is prescribed.

To approach this problem, we are looking to find the sensitivity of $J$ with respect to $a$ or $\frac{\delta J}{\delta a}$. To get this quantity, use the method of Lagrange multipliers to add the constraint to the objective function

\begin{align}
J = \int_{\Omega} c u \ dV +  \int_{\Omega}\lambda \left[\nabla \cdot (a \nabla u) - f \right] dV
\end{align}

Note that I'm dropping the function arguments to be more concise. Take the variation of $J$

\begin{align}
\delta J = \int_{\Omega} c (\delta u) \ dV + \int_{\Omega}\lambda\left[\nabla \cdot (\delta a \nabla u) + \nabla \cdot (a \nabla \delta u)\right] dV
\end{align}

Now integrate the following term by parts twice
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} \lambda \nabla \cdot (a \nabla \delta u) &= \int_{\partial \Omega} \lambda a (\nabla \delta u) \cdot d\vec{S} - \int_{\Omega} (a \nabla \delta u) \cdot \nabla \lambda dV \\
&= \int_{\partial \Omega} \lambda a (\nabla \delta u) \cdot d\vec{S} - \int_{\partial \Omega} \delta u (a \nabla \lambda) \cdot d\vec{S} + \int_{\Omega} \delta u (\nabla \cdot (a \nabla \lambda )) dV
\end{align}

Recombining this term with the expression for $\delta J$ we get

\begin{align}
\delta J = \int_{\Omega} \left(c +  \nabla \cdot (a \nabla \lambda ) \right)\delta u \ dV + \int_{\Omega}\lambda\nabla \cdot (\delta a \nabla u) dV + \int_{\partial \Omega} \lambda a (\nabla \delta u) \cdot d\vec{S} - \int_{\partial \Omega} \delta u (a \nabla \lambda) \cdot d\vec{S}
\end{align}

Then since we are looking for a relationship between $\delta J$ and $\delta a$ we can choose $\lambda$ such that the first term goes to zero. Since $\delta u$ is not, in general, $0$ then we must have
\begin{align}
c +  \nabla \cdot (a \nabla \lambda) = 0
\end{align}
which is our **adjoint PDE** (also Poisson's equation) which can be solved for $\lambda$.

Now integrate the second term by parts and we get

\begin{align}
\delta J =  - \int_{\Omega} \delta a \nabla u \cdot \nabla \lambda dV + \int_{\partial \Omega} \lambda \delta a \nabla u \cdot d\vec{S} + \int_{\partial \Omega} \lambda a (\nabla \delta u) \cdot d\vec{S} - \int_{\partial \Omega} \delta u (a \nabla \lambda) \cdot d\vec{S}
\end{align}

But here is where my understanding breaks down. In the video, it is declared that

\begin{align}
\frac{\delta J}{\delta a} = \nabla \lambda \cdot \nabla u
\end{align}

So I have the following questions:

1. What happens to the boundary terms? Can we assume that all the
   variations are $0$ at the boundaries? Are their gradients also $0$? How
   do the boundary conditions of the forward problem factor in here?
2. How do we pull $\delta a$ out of the integral? and what happened to
   the minus sign?
3. What are the boundary conditions of the adjoint PDE?

Any tips or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that u=0 on the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I was watching the same video and had the same questions.
He explicitly says that we have $\lambda = 0$ on the boundaries in order to get rid of the first surface integral. (We are free to chose the boundary conditions for $\lambda$)

Since we apply a Dirichlet boundary condition to $u$, the variation $\delta u$ is zero on the boundaries since $u$ is fixed. Which removes the other surface integral too.

The inegral relation below is like a global view, it gives you the change in the objective functional $J$ when you perturb the function $\delta a$.
Note that $\delta a$ is a function of x.

$\delta J = -\int_{\Omega} \delta a \nabla \phi \nabla u dx$

It makes intuitively sense to go from the integral relation to the differential relation below. Since the integral change is like a large sum of local changes, the differential relation is like a local view. If you change $\delta a(x)$ locally, it tells how this affects $J$ locally.

$\frac{\partial J}{\partial a} = -\nabla \phi \nabla u$

(Ans yes, he forgot the minus in his derivation)